# Auth for connecting to Bigtable from a compute instance

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have an app connecting to Google Bigtable using the `com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection` class. This is running inside a compute engine VM which has the default scopes set plus the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data` scope (required for reading/writing to Bigtable). The connection works fine when the property `google.bigtable.auth.json.keyfile` is set to the appropriate auth file.

However, I want to avoid setting this property and just use the scopes set for the instance, so that the key file does not have to be kept on the instance. This does not seem to work. The error message is

```
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:230)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:211)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:144)
    at com.google.bigtable.admin.v2.BigtableTableAdminGrpc$BigtableTableAdminBlockingStub.listTables(BigtableTableAdminGrpc.java:371)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableTableAdminGrpcClient.listTables(BigtableTableAdminGrpcClient.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableAdmin.requestTableList(AbstractBigtableAdmin.java:258)
    ... 8 more
```

Is there any other way of doing this or is there a configuration property I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out that it requires both the access scope as well as the correct IAM role to be assigned to the instance, and then it works. The scopes are

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.admin.table
```

and the IAM role should include the `Bigtable User` role.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!